# What is the best process to create a laminated panel with MDF core, linoleum & veneer faces, and edge banding?

Tags: wood, mdf, veneer, edge-banding

what is the best process to create MDF with linoleum on one side, veneer on the other and edge banding? The result should look like this. Mine doesn't come close and I am unsure about the best approach.

[image]

My initial idea was to apply the veneer and linoleum to a 8x4' sheet, cut it to size, apply the edge banding and use a trim router with a flush trim bit on the edge bending. However, the edge banding ends up covering the linoleum on the side. Second idea was to apply the veneer, cut the sheet to size, apply the edge banding and finally the linoleum. However, when I use a router to trim the linoleum, it always damages the edges. Below is a pic (tried this without edge banding to see how the trimming goes). I also tried a slightly angles trim but for laminate with better results but still problematic.

Any suggestions for the order of steps you would take? Or particular tools and material to ease the process?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: *"However, when I use a router to trim the linoleum, it always damages the edges."* Take shallower cuts. You want to make sure the bit is very sharp, and completely clean (dirty bits act as though they were blunter than they are) but shallower passes stand the best chance of giving a good outcome, with the final pass being a 'dust pass' where you skim off nearly nothing (the thickness of tape perhaps). But this all assumes that lino can be cut successfully by router, I'm not sure it can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the order in your last technique you described but with these details :

1. Cut the MDF to shape
2. Apply the banding to the edge
3. Use flush cut router to trim the banding to thickness of the MDF
4. Apply veneer to the one side of MDF
5. Use flush cut to trim veneer to match the edges – Do not round yet
6. Apply linoleum on the other side of MDF
7. Use flush cut bit to trim linoleum to match the edges – use enough pressure to be able to do the trimming.  Do not use a lot of force when pressing the router against the edge to trip.
8. Use the flush rounding cove bit with light pressure to just cut the corners of the edges.  Make multiple light passes vs hard pressure to do it in one pass.
9. Use fine sandpaper to finish the edges.

Don’t try and trim the linoleum and round the edges at the same time. Use light pressure when trimming and rounding.

A closer examination of the linoleum trimming shows that the trim cut is good.  What is happening is that the base material of the linoleum is overheating and melting on to MDF. The cut itself is good.  You need a cleaner to rub off the material off the suface of the edge.  Also try using a lower speed on the router, the high speed of the router bit rubbing against the rubberlike base is melting it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I will try that and report back...